# Two different recommendations given for waterproofing basement. Does the (far) more expensive method add value?

Tags: basement, foundation, waterproofing

Sorry no pictures as this is not a personal project but instead a question about two different recommendations I was given by contractors when I asked them for estimates.

The house is about a hundred years old. I'm in Indianapolis. The basement is brick wall. There are horizontal cracks and what both characterized as very slight bowing inward on three of the walls. There are also two spots where water streams from the wall to the central drain during heavy rains.

Both contractors (reps for well reputed well known companies) talked about the possibility of wall anchors or I-beams however, both also said they are not seriously worried about what they saw with the existing cracks and bowing and both said they are more concerned about waterproofing. Both also said external drainage would be less economical, and more potentially damaging to the basement wall, than internal drainage. It was in the internal drainage method that they differed.

Method one involved laying a gutter down around the edges of the basement, attached to a sump pump. The gutters would be visible, and there would not be any digging into the floor concrete involved. Method one costs $8500.

Method two is similar but the gutter would be laid *under* the floor concrete. As well, some work would need to be done to be sure that the walls remain sturdily supported during the process. (I forget what he called this but it involved pouring concrete somewhere or other, and he said it's because my house "probabyl doesn't have a footer" due to its age.) Method two costs $17000.

Method two guy said his method is far superior because it catches water coming up *and* coming down the wall. (There was to be a tiny bit of the gutter sticking out of the floor, right up against the wall to catch water that may come down the wall). He said method one guy's gutter is also designed to catch water both ways but "if the epoxy fails" it won't work.

That's all the information I can recall off the top of my head. They left documents behind I can try to find info if more is needed.

But based on this, do you think the $17,000 method really is nine thousand dollars of value better than the $8500 method?

Comment: ... if the epoxy fails you can afford to do it twice (and probably won't have to if the company is in fact reputable, as they likely have some sort of guarantee for some period, and redoing the epoxy even out of warranty would be less than doing the whole job from scratch...) I've seen them done that way that worked fine.

Comment: To me that sounds like a lot for a epoxy tray on the wall that still won’t make a dry basement or method #1. Method 2 works with high groundwater and drainage from above if I wanted to use the basement yes that is a project that improves the value in my opinion, if I only wanted to catch the water on the walls I would fix the drainage from the surface, but that is not alway a full fix where the perimeter drain tile below the slab eliminates both water sources, prices are off topic but I would pay 2x to do it right if exterior excavation and drainage is out method the below slab Is far superior